# Alternative to JFileChooser on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, swing, jfilechooser

I don't like this ugly FileChooser layout in Linux.

[image]

This layout is used by any other program and is MUCH more beautiful.

[image: Screenshot]

Is this layout available in Java? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759376/alternative-to-jfilechooser

Comment: Not really duplicate as explained in Yuvi Masory's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: [this](http://code.google.com/p/gtkjfilechooser/) project is dedicated to solving the problem.

I do not believe this is a duplicate. The suggested solutions in the other questions do not help the situation in Linux (GTK at least).

- AWT's `FileDialog` looks different than `JFileChooser`, but really just as strange. It does not look like the file choosers of native GTK applications.
- `XFileDialog` is Windows-only and falls back on `JFileChooser` in GTK.
- `VFSJFileChooser` does not have improved GTK LAF as a goal.

Unfortunately I do not know of any file chooser that looks native in GTK. Hopefully someone else does.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm going to use the VFSJFileChooser in futur! Thanks

Comment: I have just developed OtrosVfsBrowser (http://code.google.com/p/otrosvfsbrowser/). I have done this to migrate from VFSJFileChooser in OtrosLogViewer. OtrosVfsBrowser reads VFSJFileChooser bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

The *gtkjfilechooser* is not working with newer JDK's like JDK7. This was [reported](http://code.google.com/p/gtkjfilechooser/issues/detail?id=84) 2011, but is not fixed yet.

On the other side, the AWT [`FileDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) has been improved with Java 7 - including multiple file selection. Check linked JavaDoc for .

> AWT's FileDialog looks different than JFileChooser, but really just as strange. It does not look like the file choosers of native GTK applications.

Talking about FileDialog of JDK7, this is *not* true anymore. Now, it looks ***exactly*** like the native one.

---

Btw., the same issue occurs on *OS X*, the it's `JFileChooser` doesn't look very *native* too. Apple recommends the usage of `FileDialog` instead of `JFileChooser`:

> Although each has its advantages, java.awt.FileDialog makes your
>   applications behave more like a native Mac app. This dialog
>   *[FileDialog]*, *[...]*, looks much like a Finder window in OS X.
>
> *[...]*
>
> The Swing dialog, *[...]*, looks much less like an OS X dialog.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Unless you need a functional advantage of JFileChooser, use FileDialog instead.

[*(Source)*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/java/conceptual/java14development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001909-212760)

Last sentence seems to be common (for all *NIX?) between Linux and OS X. So finally:

If you **don't** have a (functional) **reason** for `JFileChooser`, use AWT's `FileDialog` **instead**.

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to get filtering by extension working in FileDialog in a platform independent manner.