# How to replace the simple panel when right click on the window of JFileChooser with something like the Context Menu of Windows

Tags: java, windows, contextmenu, jfilechooser, right-click

I'm writing a simple Java application that uses JFileChooser. However when interacting with the JFileChooser Panel, I want every time I right click on a file, it should trigger the context menu we often see in Windows, with buttons "Select", "Open", "Open in a new window" etc. Do I need some APIs to invoke this Windows function?

Comment: My gut says this is impossible. The JFileChooser is a pretty opaque widget that can differ wildly between Look-and-Feels.

Comment: the accepted answer in the following post might be just what you need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759376/alternative-to-jfilechooser